# How to extract Excel rows from uploaded Base64String into List<Object>

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a method that will take the uploaded Excel file that is the **documentUploadModel** and then converts each row from the original Excel into object of **ReportRow** that is then put into **List**. I'm not sure how to start here.

```
public async Task<List<ReportRow>> ProcessReport(DocumentUploadModel documentUploadModel) 
{
   var documentByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(documentUploadModel.Base64EncodeString);
}
```

I tried looking online but could not find anything that seemed to fit my need here. Will be happy for any help.

Comment: You'll need a library that can parse Excel documents, e.g. https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML - btw. it typically makes no sense to base64 encode uploads, it's just more bytes to transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0), to upload file in Asp.net Core application, we should use the IFormFile, then the files uploaded using the IFormFile technique are buffered in memory or on disk on the server before processing.

From your description, if you are using Base64 string, first, you could convert it to a byte array, then export to an excel file (it is temporary, you can delete it after reading the data). After that you could use `System.Data.OleDb` package or `ClosedXML` library to read  data from the excel file. More detail information, you could refer the following sample code:

**Use the `System.Data.OleDb` package**

1. Prerequisites:

   Install the `System.Data.OleDb` package via NuGet.
   Downloading and installing [Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Download-MicrosoftACEOLEDB120-provider-for-32bit-and-64bit.aspx)
2. Excel data:

   [image]
3. Create Models:

   ```
    //based on the excel file table structure, create a model
    public class StudentInfo
    {
        [Key]
        public int studentId { get; set; }
        public string studentName { get; set; }
        public int studentGrade { get; set; }
    }
    //View Model, user will use it to submit data and selected the excel file.
    public class FileViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IFormFile File { get; set; } 
    }

    //this model is used to store data into database.
    public class AppFile
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte[] Content { get; set; } //byte array to store the file data.        
    }
   ```
4. Controller:

   ```
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _hostingEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
    }

    public IActionResult FileUpload()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> FileUploadAsync(FileViewModel fileviewmodel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var file = new AppFile();

            //upload file to database.
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await fileviewmodel.File.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

                // Upload the file if less than 2 MB
                if (memoryStream.Length < 2097152)
                {
                    file.Name = fileviewmodel.Name;
                    file.Content = memoryStream.ToArray();

                    //_context.AppFiles.Add(file);
                    //_context.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("File", "The file is too large.");
                }
            }

            //From your description, if you are using base64 string.
            var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(file.Content); 

            //convert the base64 string to byte array.
            byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

            //export the excel file to a temp file.
            var filePath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "files/" + fileviewmodel.File.FileName);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, fileBytes);

            //Read the connection string for the Excel file.
            string conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            conString = string.Format(conString, filePath);

            //Taken List of data from json file which we want to export to excel.
            List<StudentInfo> stulist = new List<StudentInfo>();

            //import the excel data.
            try
            {
                conString = string.Format(conString, filePath);

                using (OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conString))
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand())
                    {
                        using (OleDbDataAdapter odaExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                        {
                            cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

                            //Get the name of First Sheet.  
                            connExcel.Open();
                            DataTable dtExcelSchema;
                            dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                            string sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                            connExcel.Close();

                            //Read Data from First Sheet.  
                            connExcel.Open();
                            cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";
                            odaExcel.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
                            odaExcel.Fill(dt);
                            connExcel.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            }

            //loop through the datatable and convert it to list.
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    StudentInfo student = new StudentInfo();
                    student.studentId = Convert.ToInt32(row["studentId"]);
                    student.studentName = row["studentName"].ToString();
                    student.studentGrade = Convert.ToInt32(row["studentGrade"]); 
                    stulist.Add(student);
                }
            }

            return View(stulist);
        }
        return View();
    }
   ```
5. View Page:

   ```
    @model WebApplication2.Data.FileViewModel

    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "FileUpload";
    }

    <h1>FileUpload</h1>

    <h4>FileViewModel</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="FileUpload">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <dl>
                        <dt>
                            <label asp-for="File"></label>
                        </dt>
                        <dd>
                            <input asp-for="File" type="file">
                        </dd>
                    </dl>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
   ```

The debug screenshot like this:

[image]

**Use the `ClosedXML` library**

Prerequisites: Install the `ClosedXML` library via the NuGet.

Then, after export the base64 string to a temporary excel file, you could use the following code to retrieve data:

```
    //Taken List of data from json file which we want to export to excel.
    List<StudentInfo> stulist = new List<StudentInfo>();
    //required  using ClosedXML.Excel;        
    //Open the Excel file using ClosedXML.
    using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(filePath)) //refer previous code to get the file path.
    {
        //Read the first Sheet from Excel file.
        IXLWorksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheet(1);
        //Loop through the Worksheet rows.
        bool firstRow = true;
        foreach (IXLRow row in workSheet.Rows())
        {
            //Use the first row to add columns to DataTable.
            if (firstRow)
            {
                foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                }
                firstRow = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Add rows to DataTable.
                dt.Rows.Add();
                int i = 0;
                foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                {
                    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell.Value.ToString();
                    i++;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (!(row[0] is DBNull))
            {
                StudentInfo student = new StudentInfo();
                student.studentId = Convert.ToInt32(row[0]);
                student.studentName = row[1].ToString();
                student.studentGrade = Convert.ToInt32(row[2]);
                stulist.Add(student);
            }
        }
    }
```